# Access JSON array within Laravel foreach loop

Tags: php, json, laravel, foreach, laravel-5.4

I have a function that returns data that I need to manipulate within the view. The data is linked from various tables based on relationships:

**Function:**

```
$auditResults = Audit::where('audit_id', $id)
   ->with('question', 'question.auditQuestion')
   ->get();
```

**View:**

```
@foreach($auditResults as $answer)
    <p>{{$answer}}</p>
@endforeach
```

**Output of $answer:**

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "audit_id":1,
   "audit_questions_details_id":2,
   "question":{  
      "id":2,
      "audit_question_id":2,
      "question_number":1,
      "comment":1,
      "header":0,
      "created_at":"2017-03-27 12:16:50",
      "updated_at":"2017-03-27 12:16:50",
      "audit_question":{  
         "id":2,
         "audit_detail_id":1,
         "question":"THIS IS WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO OUTPUT",
         "created_at":"2017-03-27 12:16:50",
         "updated_at":"2017-03-27 12:16:50"
      }
   },
   "score":null,
   "comment":null,
   "created_at":null,
   "updated_at":null
}
```

Within the `foreach` loop, how can I output the `question` parameter of each result?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p>{{$answer->question->audit_question->question}}</p>
```

getting question number

```
<p>{{$answer->question->question_number}}</p>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It's really odd how I can see the 18 results of `$answer`, and when I only output `{{ $answer->question }}` it returns integers of 1 - 18. Yet when I try to access the `question` relationship, I get `Trying to get property of non-object`. Why is that?

Comment: Its could be that its not all the audit that have a question. so you can do an if statement to check if question contains somethings before you try to access it attributes/properties

Answer (score 0):

If `$answer` is really an JSON **(string)**, so you must decode it first:

```
@foreach($auditResults as $answer)
    <?php $answer = json_decode($answer) ?>
    <!-- Now you have access to an PHP StdObject with your data -->
    <p>{{$answer->question}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
{{ $answer->question->comment }}
```

Comment: this will not work in a loop